# Laravel thinks that my PHP version does not meet their minimum requirement even if it isn't

Tags: php, apache, laravel, cpanel

I changed my php version into `5.6` but when i run `composer update` it still thinks I am using 5.4 version.

The version of my server is `5.4` but I changed my project directory php version in to `5.6`. I changed that one via cpanel php configuration. Here's the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see i changed my project directory php version in to 5.6, but when i run composer update, it still thinks that i am using 5.4 version.

I also tried adding this in my composer.json:

```
"platform": {
            "php": "5.5.9"
        }
```

And when I run composer update, it installs some dependencies except for the last one..it is giving me this error:

```
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home3/idmadm/public_html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 146
```

When I checked line 146 of helpers.php, this is the code:

```
function auth($guard = null)
{
    if (is_null($guard)) {
        return app(AuthFactory::class); //THIS IS THE CODE!!
    } else {
        return app(AuthFactory::class)->guard($guard);
    }
}
```

I researched about that error and some said it's because of my PHP Version. I guess Laravel still think that my PHP Version is 5.4 where in fact, i changed it into 5.6.

How can i let Laravel know that I am using PHP Version 5.6.

Any help please!

Your help will be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

PS: The reason why I am changing PHP version in the directory because some websites that are hosted in my server do not support PHP 5.5+.

Comment: Systems can have multiple versions of PHP. E.g. you could have one version for web, but another one getting used for CLI.

Comment: I am wondering if you run 5.6 with your webserver, but 5.4 on your CLI (command line). That could be a reason why `composer` thinks you are running 5.4. Can you run `php -v` on your CLI and check the version?

Comment: @codedge yes composer thinks i am running 5.4 because when i run `php -v` it is showing `5.4.45` , any ideas how to make composer think that I am using 5.6 same with my webserver?

Comment: You'd need to install the correct version of PHP CLI SAPI.

Comment: That is not an error in composer! Your server is configured to run PHP 5.4 on your CLI. You need to find out how to change the running PHP on your command line. Maybe you should contact the support hotline for your server or you find out how to configure the PHP version for the command line with CPanel.

Comment: @codedge i guess i have to contact our hosting support - doing that now. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem. Just let us know what's the outcome and how you (hopefully) solved the problem.

Comment: Just CD to where PHP 5.6 is located and run php composer from there. It will run that version instead of the one assigned to you system variables.

Answer (score 0):

Remove composer and install again. Because when you install composer, it is written the route of php folder as path. And you should update this path now.

Answer (score 0):

Normal server with  cpanel has 2 PHP:

- PHP for internal use /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/
- other for use with apache on /usr/local/lib.

Sysadmin install composer over /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/ and this it's now, PHP 5.4.31

```
 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php -v
```

You have two option.

- Speak with your hosting for Sysadmin install composer using PHP uses be Apache
- Instal composer on your shared account (best way)